# Objective C UIActionSheet is it possible to fill Title with a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uiactionsheet

I know about addButtonWithTitle function, but I dont want to create new buttons, only to fill the Title area in an UIActionSheet.

If it is possible, is it possible with UIAlertView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSMutableString *mstr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for (NSString *s in array)
        [mstr appendString:s];
    UIActionSheet*actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:mstr ......
    [actionSheet showInView:view];
    [actionSheet release];

    [mstr release];
```

This is assuming yer array contains strings.
Similar approach for UIAlertView.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! By the way, I changed it to `[mstr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@\n", s]];`

Comment: yeah, wasn't sure if you had the newlines in the strings or not, no worries ;)